# Avoid memory issue while using viewBinding in customView

Tags: android, kotlin, memory, android-custom-view, android-viewbinding

Based on [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) when we use ViewBinding in fragments, we should set binding to null in `onDestroyView` of the fragment:

```
private var _binding:MainFragmentBinding?=null
private val binding get()=_binding!!

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

What about custom views? Do we need to set binding to null in `onDetachFromWindow` or any other function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is fine to just have it in `val`.

The issue with fragments is that Fragment and its view have different lifecycles, so holding onto the binding in fragment between `onDestroyView()` and `onDestroy()` uses unnecessary memory.

In custom views, it has same lifecycle as any binding stored in a class property.